# Observe object property changes on existing object

Tags: javascript

It used to be possible to call [`Object.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) on any object and then receive callbacks when properties were modified. However, it was deprecated and we were given [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) as alternatives. But neither one allows attaching a listener to an existing object, references to which are already stored elsewhere. Taking this code as an example:

```
const state = {};

/* BEGIN Third party code */
(function runProcessing() {
    setInterval(globalState => {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            globalState.attr = !globalState.attr;
        }
    }, 1000, state);
})();
/* END Third party code */

// TODO: run some function every time state.attr is changed
```

There are two immediate problems:

- `state` is declared a `const`, so it can't be redefined using Proxy
- `state` was passed by reference to an inner function, so even if `state` is redefined, the function will continue working with the original object

While this can be achieved using `setInterval` that constantly compares the `state.attr` to previous version of itself, it would fail to catch changes that happen in between the `setInterval` invocations and it would always have lag.

Are there any lesser known methods that can achieve this?

Comment: Use `Object.defineProperties` resp. `Object.defineProperty` to create getters and setters on existing objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Defining_a_getter_on_existing_objects_using_defineProperty

Comment: @connexo, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) resp. [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Defining_a_getter_on_existing_objects_using_defineProperty) to create getters and setters on existing objects.